# Searching Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to search for specific users, using a form with a text input. Right now I'm testing the connection and var_dump the array on the page to see if my search is returning any results. Currently with the following code I'm able to connect to my database and pull in the correct users if I only search for the last name. If I search for the first and last name it returns no results in the array. What am I doing wrong here?

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
                $keyword = $_POST['user'];
                $skuser = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last LIKE '%$keyword%';");

                var_dump($skusers);
                }
```

This is WordPress on a custom page template as you can see from my code snippet I'm using the $wpdb global database variable. Again, this does work if I type in someones last name but if I type their entire name it can't find anything. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Also, I changed the table_name from my actual table name above so that isn't the issue my connection to the database works.

Comment: Have a sample data set and input strings? Might be missing something, but seems like it should be working as you're expecting, from what I see here

Comment: To answer that I would have to know the schema, and at least some idea of the data.  I think your table name is wrong ... `table_name` Just kidding.  The query looks fine except for the SQLInjection vulnerability

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I was wondering about the SQL injection as well - does WP get_results function handle that? Didn't want to comment on sql injection when I didn't know.

Comment: You don't need this `;`, isn't wordpress just  `$wpdb->get_results(SELECT .. WHERE blah=%s',"%{$var}%")`  it's like `sprintf`  @TCooper  Concatenation is Concatenation , you should never put a variable right into SQL.

Comment: @WordPressFreddie as a general rule, you'll want to use the [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method to sanitize user input before using it in your queries.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice cabrerahector, ArtisticPhoenix and TCooper! I'm going to look into that as I don't want to leave it vunerable to injection! This is on a development server right now so nbd but it will go live eventually.

Comment: @cabrerahector I've changed it to include prepare what do you think? $skusers = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(`first`, ' ', `last`) LIKE '%%d%'", $_POST['user']));

Comment: The `%d` placeholder expects an integer value, and from your code it seems you'll want to use a string instead (the `%s` placeholder). So: `$skusers = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(first, ' ', last) LIKE %s", array('%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $keyword ) . '%')) );`

Comment: @cabrerahector I realized that quickly after posting that but your solution works perfectly. I most definitely have a lot to learn after researching the vulnerabilities of SQL injection!

Comment: Also, whoever gave me the -1 I was just wondering why? Just trying to improve my experience here no hate.

Comment: Security is a serious business, @WordPressFreddie. Always remember the Golden Rule: **don't trust user input, ever**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE CONCAT( nameFirst,' ', nameLast ) LIKE  '%Noman%'
```

sanitize any user submitted input before applying in the query or use MYSQLi

Comment: This works perfectly thank you so much! I'll have to do some research into why it works now. I'll make it as the answer once it lets me!

Comment: sure !! do your research bro.

but some people on StackOverflow giving negative vote without checking it. as just one I got on this answer :(

Comment: Hopefully more people will vote you up now that I marked it as the answer!

Comment: @ShahbazZafar I downvoted because while your code works, it still isn't a good answer. There's no explanation of what you're doing, why you change the database fields and variables as you did, and nothing telling why the original code provided by WordPressFreddie is invalid. We want to be a community of learning, not of blindly copying and pasting without knowing why.

Comment: @ShahbazZafar (seems I'm not the only one who feels this way) if you update this to actually add to the knowledge base that is stack overflow, I'll gladly remove the downvote and upvote instead.
Either way, glad he was able to solve your problem WordPressFreddie

Comment: @TCooper i don't say anything to you it's your right, but who asked a question he got a solution and I am satisfied because he is happy with my answer your vote would not bother me. My aim is only to give the answer. Thanks for your vote TCooper bro.

Comment: @TCooper its ok bro, I can understand what you are demanding from me, but his aim right now to completion of the task with minimal info. I just told him to sanitize the input and if he does little more search on it. he will understand how CONCAT give him different ways to search in DB.